# Navigating Object Hierarchy in Debugger

Tags: ios, debugging, uiview, lldb

Suppose I have some code including the following:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
[self.view addSubView:myView];
```

And I step through the code in the debugger until I get to the next line after this code. On the left side of the debugger window is a list of object that I can inspect, and myView is listed there. However, I don't see where details of the frame, or the myView.center coordinates are located. Can I not inspect these properties through the object hierarchy I just described? If not, how can I inquire what the values are without using NSLog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the debugger command `po`

Example output:

```
(lldb) po theView
(UIView *) $1 = 0x09b83750 <UIView: 0x9b83750; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); layer = <CALayer: 0x9b837b0>>
```

Comment: Thanks. That gets me what I want. And it also revealed my problem. My view was being positioned propertly, but it had a frame of zero width and height. That explains why it wasn't showing.